# Svelte Vite / svite does not HMR SPA router pages

Tags: routes, single-page-application, svelte, vite

I now use Vite (svite) for my SPA Svelte app.
This app uses a hash router that uses `<svelte:component this={...} />` to load page components from the src/pages directory.

But svite HMR does not detect page changes of pages loaded by the router from src/pages.

HMR works fine for components imported by pages from the src/lib directory.
And if a page is dependent on a store and I update the store, this page also reloads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Svelte component filenames in pages and admin did not start with a capital. Example: home.svelte => Home.svelte and now HMR works fine.

On windows at least the case difference between the component file name and the import was not reported.